# How can I run my physical device as an emulator on vs-code?

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code, android-emulator

I'm currently learning Flutter development and all I have is the web emulator on vs-code I tried to use a virtual device as an emulator but didn't work and tried to connect my physical device too but didn't work either, the problem is that vs-code is not recognizing any of them!
How do I connect my physical device to use it as an emulator, knowing that the USB debugging option is turned on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.You have to enable developer options in your testing device and then turn on usb debugging.

2.Then use this command in vs code:

flutter run -d device-name

Ex-flutter run -d s3789

Comment: I have the developer options enabled, and do you mean by the device name the one in the device information?
Update**
I just tried it didn't detect my device

Comment: Yeah, you got it right.

Comment: vs-code didn't detect any device

Comment: Is there any problem in your usb cable, check it using file explorer, if it shows your testing device data then everything's fine, otherwise your usb cable is damaged.

Comment: the cable is fine i use it to transfer data all the time

Comment: is there any possible way to get the android SDK without the android studio?
I just found out that I don't have it

Comment: Yes, you can download android sdk, try this link: https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platform-tools